# Captions overlapping in list of figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, formatting

While trying to get the formatting right in my thesis, I have run into an issue where the figure captions in the list of figures are overlapping. I spent quite a bit of time in trying to create a MWE because the university template contained a lot of code which I don't understand. Also, the bug seems especially sinister, with random changes seemingly causing it to appear and disappear.

Below is the MWE that I could manage ...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, margin = 1in}
    \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\figure{%  Removes the extra space added before new chapters
  \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip-10pt}\fi
}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \caption{dummy text 1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Beginning}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \caption{dummy text 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output
[image: Overlapping captions in list of figures]

Comment: `\ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip-10pt}\fi`, why you require negative space for LOF? Omit it and see if your problem will disappear.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you, this indeed resolves the issue. This was code from my university template. Could you please explain a bit more for my understanding?

Comment: \chapter uses `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%`   \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%` to add gaps, the code was intentded to remove those gaps.  One could do a better job with etoolbox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The code does use etoolbox though, so why is the code here causing the captions to overlap rather than removing the gaps?

Comment: `\vskip-10pt` in your \addconztents` xonnabd require that the line will be moved up for 10 pt. Consequently, lines in LOF (List of Figures) are moved up. By this is probably someone have been try (wrongly) to compensate double spacing in document.

Comment: @Zarko I still don't understand this. Why would the lines overlap if all the lines in LOF are getting moved up?

Comment: due to `vskip-10pt` commands. it move each caption in collected in LOF for 10 pt up.

Comment: @Zarko If each caption gets moved up by 10pt, then all captions should get moved up by 10pt, which is probably what the author intended to do as well. I don't see why this would cause the captions to overlap.

Comment: see received answer. you also should read some introductory text about LaTeX ... This command moved caption up relatively to text above it, i.e. it reduce vertical space between paragraphs for 10 pt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this flies with your university.  Note that the LOF is still double spaced (unless you remove setspace), but at least it isn't triple spaced.  (And see if you can convince them that double spacing should only apply to typewriters.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose, margin = 1in}
    \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \caption{dummy text 1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Beginning}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a.png}
    \caption{dummy text 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```